# Spring MVC post back to same page with query params?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags, query-string

I have an index.jsp per spring mvc 3.x that contains a drop down list box.

What is the easiest way to post back to the same page but with query params per the selected item in the list?

myPage/index.jsp `(http://localhost:8085/mypage)`

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" action="myController/indexSubmit" method="post">
        <select name="selectList" class="form-control" placeholder=".input-medium" height>
            <c:forEach items="${theList}" var="item" varStatus="count"> 
                <option value="${count.index}">${item }</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>   
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium">Submit</button>   
    </form>
```

->`http://localhost:8085/GameAnalytics?selectedItem=3`

I have tried using a postback to redirect back to /index doesn't seem to be working.

```
@RequestMapping(value="indexSubmit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String indexSubmit( @RequestParam String selectList, ModelMap model) {
    System.out.println("Selected Title: " + selectList);
    return "forward:/index?item=" + selectList;  // add query params and redirect back to main index page.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `return "redirect:index?item=" + selectList;`

Comment: I did find something that works but not sure if best practice. String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");  return "redirect:"+ referer;....less query params...but at least it redirects back to originating page.

Comment: ok so this worked....your solution did work.  However, is that the best/easiest way to handle this case...a post back to the same page?

Comment: It depends, btw is there anything wrong with this in your case?

Answer (score 0):

try ajax for form submission.

var str = $("#myForm").serialize();

$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    data:str,
    url:"indexSubmit",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(){
       alert("success");
    }
});